# Sensors data-sheet is unclear about resolution of readings

Tags: sensor, resolution

This sensor states that its lower detectable limit is 1ppm yet its resolution is 0.1ppm.
What is the difference between resolution and lower-detectable limit?
I thought resolution was the smallest increment that a sensor could notice.
E.g, for this sulfur dioxide sensor, it can notice a change in concentration from 2ppm to 2.1ppm.
The data-sheet is here:
https://au.mouser.com/datasheet/2/18/1/DS_0394_PS1PS4_SO2_50-2999407.pdf

Comment: honestly, the difference is really explained in the name. The lower-detectable limit is the lowest magnitude that it can still detect. And resolution is how finely-grained observations are. Does that help?

Comment: I think it does now. Yep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolution means most of all the bit width of the digitized values, disregarding the potential of noisy bits. A 24-bit ADC has a resolution of approximately 0.1 ppmFS.

Detectability is an analog quantity physically limited by system 1/f noise. Ideally, the resolution is a bit better than the detectability, to not needlessly give up performance.

Answer (score 3):

This wall chart has a resolution of 2.5 cm and a lowest detectable limit of 60 cm.

[image]
Source: notonthehightstreet.com